# Java, creating an array of StringBuffer

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with Java.

Suppose n is an integer, I want to create an array of StringBuffer containing all the 26^n combinations of letters of the alphabet, with the lexicographic order. I obtain ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I wrote this class:

```
public static StringBuffer[] creaTabellaTotale(int n, char[] a) {   


     StringBuffer[] tabella = new StringBuffer[ pow(26, n)];
     for(int w =0; w < pow(26, n); w++)
         tabella[w] = new StringBuffer("");

     for(int h = 1; h <= n ; h++){
        for(int u =0; u < pow ( 26, h-1); u++){

        for (int j = 0; j<26; j++){

            for( int x =pow(26, n-h+1)*u + pow(26, n-h)*j; x< pow(26, n-h+1)*u + pow(26, n-h)*(j+1); x++)
                tabella[x] = tabella[x].append(a[j]);
        }

        }

     }

     return tabella;
 }
```

Here a[] is an array containing the 26 letters in alphabetic order; I have rewritten pow(), its prototype is int pow(int b, int e). I'm not able to find the error.

Comment: Hmmm what error? (it throws an exception? it does not calculate the correct combinations? ...)

Comment: `26^n` is quite large; even for an `n` as small as `5` it becomes `11881376`. You can't even go past `n = 6` because you can't create an array that large (the value surpasses int's max value).

Comment: yes what is the error? what kinds of values of n are you trying? Won't take a big n for your int to be insufficient storage

Comment: Yes, the exception is ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException. So, how can I create on ordered list of the 26^n words?

Comment: ok in that case the problem is certainly with the assignment value of x

Comment: for what do you need this? for brute-force-hacking?

Comment: @mmirwaldt no, it's academic stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using recursion instead of normal iteration; code is much more clear and shorter - it's easier to find bugs.

```
String[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
"u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
final int amount = 26; //alphabet.size()
StringBuffer[] foo = new StringBuffer[pow(amount, n)];
long counter = 0;

public void recursion(int depth, StringBuffer actual)
{
    String a = actual.toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        foo[counter++] = new StringBuffer(a + alphabet[i]);
        if (depth != 1)
            recursion(depth - 1, new StringBuffer(a + alphabet[i]));
    }
}
```

And just call `recursion(n, "")`.

Answer (score 3):

In your last ***for***:

```
for( int x =pow(26, n-h+1)*u + pow(26, n-h)*j; x< pow(26, n-h+1)*u + pow(26, n-h)*(j+1); x++)
            tabella[x] = tabella[x].append(a[j]);
```

You are trying to access your array with a indexbigger than your array. You may not have realized but your ***int x*** became bigger than your array precisely here:

```
x =pow(26, n-h+1)*u + pow(26, n-h)*j
```

**EDIT:**

As @d'alar'cop said in his comment: your mathematical operation is faulty

Comment: you should probably say why exactly his expression pushes x out of range... ie what mathematical operation is faulty.. and why, ideally

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious, sorry and thanks

Comment: @drurenia but when h = 1, u = 0

Comment: I have controlled my method, the mathematical part is correct because now it works; It was a heap problem.